# Read CSV file in PySpark Streaming with different schema on the same file

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file that has different lenghts per row, similar to:

```
left, 10, xdfe, 8992, 0.231
left, 10, xdfk, 8993, 2.231
right, 20, adfk, 8993, 2.231, DDT, 10, 10
right, 30, dfk, 923, 2.231, ADD, 10, 20
center, 923, 2.231, 10, 20
right, 34, efk, 326, 6.21, DDD, 20, 40
```

where rows that start with a keyword, `left`, `right` and `center` have the same length (the `left` rows always have the same length as other `left` rows, for example).

I want to read these files using `spark.readStream.csv`, do some transformations that can depend on the kind of row, and write the results to parquet. Is there a way to use different schemas based on the value of the first column of each row?

Comment: You could filter your dataset based on the first column then operate on each identifier independently

Comment: But how can I filter the dataset is it's being ingested?

Comment: I assume you meant "as being ingested". Maybe you're misunderstanding that Dataframe operations are lazy? No computations are performed until an action. In other words, 3 filter operations after "reading" the file (as a stream) is not inefficient. And that's the only way to do what you want... In other words, are you able to get any dataframe? Have you been able to split the rows into columns?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use multiple schemas for the same file. The best you can do is to use the schema for the longest row and set the `mode` to `PERMISSIVE`, this will give null values in the missing columns for the shorter rows.

Unfortunately, this means that the type and column names will be different if the missing columns are not at the end of the row. E.g. the third column is a string for the `right` rows can a float for the `center` rows (looks like it should be the fifth column). One way would be to read everything as strings and then do the conversion, but depending on the data some columns can be read as e.g. float.

```
schema = StructType().add("a", "string").add("b", "string") \
    .add("c", "string").add("d", "string").add("e", "string") \
    .add("f", "string").add("g", "string").add("h", "string")

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv("/path/to/directory")
```

After this is done, it's possible to make some transformations of the data to get a correct looking dataframe. Below code is in Scala but should be easy to transform to python and adjusted to the actual needs:

```
val df2 = df.select($"a", 
    when($"a" === "center", null).otherwise($"b").cast(FloatType).as("b"),
    when($"a" === "center", null).otherwise($"c").as("c"),
    when($"a" === "center", $"b").otherwise($"d").cast(FloatType).as("d"),
    when($"a" === "center", $"c").otherwise($"e").cast(FloatType).as("e"),
    $"f", $"g", $"h")
```

Final result:

```
+------+----+-----+------+-----+----+----+----+
|     a|   b|    c|     d|    e|   f|   g|   h|
+------+----+-----+------+-----+----+----+----+
|  left|10.0| xdfe|8992.0|0.231|null|null|null|
|  left|10.0| xdfk|8993.0|2.231|null|null|null|
| right|20.0| adfk|8993.0|2.231| DDT|  10|  10|
| right|30.0|  dfk| 923.0|2.231| ADD|  10|  20|
|center|null| null| 923.0|2.231|null|null|null|
| right|34.0|  efk| 326.0| 6.21| DDD|  20|  40|
+------+----+-----+------+-----+----+----+----+
```